# Javascript : Check if multiple select dropdown has same value except the first selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have multiple select option fields.

HTML

```
<select class="selectRound" name="criteriaRound[]" >
    <option selected="true" disabled="true"> - select -</option>
    <option value="16">value1</option>
    <option value="17">value2</option>
    <option value="18">value3</option>
    <option value="19">value4</option>
</select>

<select class=" selectRound" name="criteriaRound[]">
    <option selected="true" disabled="true"> - select -</option>
    <option value="16">value1</option>
    <option value="17">value2</option>
    <option value="18">value3</option>
    <option value="19">value4</option>
</select>

<select class=" selectRound" name="criteriaRound[]">
    <option selected="true" disabled="true"> - select -</option>
    <option value="16">value1</option>
    <option value="17">value2</option>
    <option value="18">value3</option>
    <option value="19">value4</option>
</select>
```

And now I am trying to validate if each of those has same value. But how to avoid the first selected index in validation. Because what happen is if i choose an option at first time, the other remaining -select- field are still validating.

https://jsfiddle.net/uhhk8vd3/2/

JS

```
$(document).on('change','.selectRound', function(e){
var tralse = true;
var selectRound_arr = []; // for contestant name
$('.selectRound').each(function(k, v){
    var getVal = $(v).val();
    if($.trim(selectRound_arr.indexOf(getVal)) != -1){ //
        tralse = false;
        //it should be if value 1 = value 1 then alert
        //But -select- = -select- are still keep validating, how to prevent this
        alert('Contestant cannot be same name');
        return false;
    }else{
        selectRound_arr.push($(v).val());
    }

});
if(!tralse){
    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: set a value="" or value="select" for the default select and if the selected option value is not null then check for your condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/uhhk8vd3/3/

```
$(document).on('change', '.selectRound', function(e) {
  var tralse = true;
  var selectRound_arr = []; // for contestant name
  $('.selectRound').each(function(k, v) {
    var getVal = $(v).val();
    //alert(getVal);
    if (getVal && $.trim(selectRound_arr.indexOf(getVal)) != -1) {
      tralse = false;
      //it should be if value 1 = value 1 then alert, and not those if -select- = -select-. how to avoid those -select-
      alert('Contestant cannot be same name');
      $(v).val("");
      return false;
    } else {
      selectRound_arr.push($(v).val());
    }

  });
  if (!tralse) {
    return false;
  }
});
```